# Referential integrity constraint violation error in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot

I am trying to parse a web request and save to database. I have 3 models and first node is virtualDocument. This is the uniq table (according to request url). VirtualRequest table has all erquest bodies and HttpHeaderList table has all thhp headers according to their virtualRequest bean id.

when I tried to save the first log I got and error like this;

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK1TW2G47F7A47580KQVMDJWGBQ: PUBLIC.T_VIRTUAL_REQUEST FOREIGN KEY(REQUEST_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.T_VIRTUAL_DOCUMENT(DOCUMENT_ID) (65)"; SQL statement:
insert into t_virtual_request (request_id, media_type, method_type, request_url) values (null, ?, ?, ?) [23506-192]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) ~[h2-1.4.192.jar:1.4.192]
```

here is VirtualDocument bean

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_virtual_document")
public class VirtualDocument {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "document_id")
    private long documentId;

    @Column(name = "real_url", unique = true)
    private String realURL; //uniq

    @Column(name = "virtual_url", unique = true)
    private String virtualURL; //uniq

    @Column(name = "simulation_mode", columnDefinition = "varchar(10) default 'STOP'")
    private String simulationMode;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "request_id")
    private List<VirtualRequest> requestList;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "response_id")
    private List<VirtualResponse> responseList;

   //getter setter without any annotation
}
```

here is VirtualRequest bean;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_virtual_request")
public class VirtualRequest {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "request_id")
    private long requestId;

    @Column(name = "request_url")
    private String requestURL;

    @Column(name = "method_type")
    private String methodType;

    @Column(name = "media_type")
    private String mediaType;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "header_id")
    private List<HttpHeaderList> requestHeaders;

   //getter setter without any annotation
}
```

here is HeaderList bean;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_http_headers")
public class HttpHeaderList {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "header_id")
    private long headerId;

    @Column(name = "header_key")
    private String headerKey;

    @Column(name = "header_value")
    private String headerValue;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you JPA mapping is not correct. If you want to have many Requests per VirtualDocument you need to have a foreign key from the VirtualRequest to the document. Then you'd use mappedBy parameter in the `@OneToMany` annotation to tell point JPA to the foreign key property.

Comment: mappedBy parameter can be something or it must be a field?

Comment: Please take a look at my answer. Mapped by points to a field in the entity that owns the relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want instead:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_virtual_document")
public class VirtualDocument {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "document_id")
    private long documentId;

    @Column(name = "real_url", unique = true)
    private String realURL; //uniq

    @Column(name = "virtual_url", unique = true)
    private String virtualURL; //uniq

    @Column(name = "simulation_mode", columnDefinition = "varchar(10) default 'STOP'")
    private String simulationMode;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "virtualDocument")
    private List<VirtualRequest> requestList;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "virtualDocument")
    // Note the mappedBy parameter. This points to the property in the entity that owns the relationship (in this case the VirtualResponse).
    private List<VirtualResponse> responseList;

   //getter setter without any annotation
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_virtual_request")
public class VirtualRequest {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "request_id")
    private long requestId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "document_id")
    private VirtualDocument virtualDocument;

    @Column(name = "request_url")
    private String requestURL;

    @Column(name = "method_type")
    private String methodType;

    @Column(name = "media_type")
    private String mediaType;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "virtualRequest")
    private List<HttpHeaderList> requestHeaders;

   //getter setter without any annotation
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_http_headers")
public class HttpHeader { /*Note this is a more appropriate name for the entity since it holds the data of a single header.*/

    @Id
    @Column(name = "header_id")
    private long headerId;

    @Column(name = "header_key")
    private String headerKey;

    @Column(name = "header_value")
    private String headerValue;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "request_id")
    private VirtualRequest virtualRequest

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "response_id")
    private VirtualResponse virtualResponse;
}
```

Updated the answer to add mapping the headers to the request entity.

Comment: @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "document_id")
    private long documentId; in this field type, must be long or VirtualDocument?

Comment: No.. My bad. It needs to be the same as the entity type. Let me fix that.

Comment: sorry for questions but, I have big problem these mapping topics, last question, my HttpHeaderList bean and other request-response beans need a mapping? if yes how? because I got an error Associations marked as mappedBy must not define database mappings like JoinTable or JoinColumn: VirtualResponse.responseHeaders

Comment: Try the updated code. Always think which entity owns a relationship (the foreign key). That entity has the `JoinColumn` annotation. The target entity has the `OneToMany` with the mappedBy param.

Comment: I think we forgot another think, If we marked mappedBy parameter we must not define JoinColumn annotation :) also mappedBy parameter must be class field's name, not db column's name. I'm just trying update

Comment: Correct! You can't have both on the same field.